# フォーム送信時に <input type="file"> で選択したファイルを無視する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, html5

HTMLのフォームで質問です。

ファイル選択で、「ファイルを選択可能だがフォームデータとして送信しない」状態を作りたいです（dataURIを抽出して同データをテキストでsubmitするため）。

disabledを有効にするとフォームデータは送られませんが、ファイル選択ができません。
上記の目的を実現するにはどのようなオプション・方法がありますか？

補足）Railsでformヘルパーを利用しているので、formタグ内で完結させたいです。

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="file">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clickイベントリスナーを設置しリスナー内でajaxで文字列のみ送信する方法はいかがでしょうか？
http://qiita.com/kazu56/items/cdbf4e371cdc699709f1

Comment: 最終的にjavascriptによる解決が現実的のようです。
時間が経ちましたのでこちらを回答としてクローズします。

Answer (score 0):

`<form>`の外に`<input type="file">`を配置すれば、`submit()`対象には含まれなくなるのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問に記載しておりませんでしたが、View生成がRailsを前提になるのでformヘルパー内で完結させたいのです。